# Deviance igual a 0

Tags: r

Tengo una duda respecto al cálculo del valor de deviance. Estoy realizando el análisis de una comunidad y relacionándola con variables ambientales por lo que me interesa tener algunos criterios de información.

Mis distintos modelos se pueden resumir en `M = a + sum(bi *x)` donde `M` es una matriz de 550x10 (550 especies en 10 sitios) y `x` son mis variables ambientales.

Cuando deseo calcular el deviance de todos mis modelos (nulos y los demás) todos me salen 0. ¿Cuáles son los motivos por los que este valor me sale 0?.

Estoy realizando el análisis en el paquete boral de R.

Esta seria mi comunidad:

```
"","sp1","sp2","sp3","sp4","sp5","sp6","sp7","sp8","sp9","sp10"
"comu_44",1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1
"comu_7",1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1
"comu_21",1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
"comu_38",1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
"comu_26",1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
"comu_2",1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
"comu_49",1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1
"comu_48",1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
"comu_23",1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1
"comu_5",1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

estos mis datos ambientales:

```
"","Cl.g.L.","SO4.g.L.","Na.g.L.","K.g.L.","Ca.g.L.","Mg.g.L.","Br.g.","B.g.L.","Li.g.L."
"comu_44",1.71963451266333,2.36109561690706,-2.39861345413745,2.33063236343157,-1.90115237334694,2.42920804871106,2.5317734458085,2.50706812722311,2.3684216334859
"comu_7",0.97196733324449,0.0897853520794281,-0.18565632817097,0.0936293982987063,-0.563150233831579,0.125352630223309,-0.0351025781047973,0.0157673117400964,0.0522013817919093
"comu_21",0.97196733324449,0.0897853520794281,-0.18565632817097,0.0936293982987063,-0.563150233831579,0.125352630223309,-0.0351025781047973,0.0157673117400964,0.0522013817919093
"comu_38",0.59813374353507,0.577583529760531,-0.790697040513867,0.761122218539965,-1.03293765170586,0.783597035505524,0.776644540568638,0.287843585009952,0.840407676398222
"comu_26",-0.14953343588377,-0.794348844967571,0.568572505023598,-0.267177531561433,0.293171135458255,-0.585837520701171,-0.430006581783766,-0.377595974915117,-0.656492874323415
"comu_2",-0.52336702559319,-0.826360600377893,0.485690215661558,-0.828232307493951,0.174237611945779,-0.677419351001306,-0.451945693099264,-0.564443536076343,-0.487097661886094
"comu_49",-0.52336702559319,-0.657155607494761,0.651454794385639,-0.884157381622273,0.560771563361328,-0.687436113690383,-0.517763027045759,-0.613613946908245,-0.732547867662621
"comu_48",-0.89720061530261,0.146949201026432,0.353078552682293,-0.0524974082946504,1.18814589988964,-0.240974690977228,-0.430006581783766,0.0337964623784604,-0.117193830645412
"comu_23",-0.89720061530261,0.146949201026432,0.353078552682293,-0.0524974082946504,1.18814589988964,-0.240974690977228,-0.430006581783766,0.0337964623784604,-0.117193830645412
"comu_5",-1.27103420501203,-1.13428320003909,1.14874853055788,-1.19445134130199,0.65591838217131,-1.03086797731589,-0.978484364671222,-1.33838580257048,-1.20270600830498
```

Este es el código que intente hasta ahora:

```r
library(boral)
comu_rich = read.csv("comu_rich.csv", header = T, row.names = 1)
fq = read.csv("fq.csv", header =T, row.names = 1)

sodium = fq$Na.g.L.

mod_sodium = boral(y = comu_rich, X = sodium, family ="binomial",trial.size = 1, n.burnin = 20000, n.iteration = 100000,save.model = T, do.fit = T, model.name = "mod_sodium.txt")

mod_sodium_mcmc = as.mcmc(mod_sodium$jags.model)
traceplot(mod_sodium_mcmc) ##traceplot for cheking convergence

ic_sodium = mod_sodium$ics
```

Comment: Ya edite el mensaje original